# Unable to install extensions, themes in Google Chrome on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. When I try to install themes, extensions for Google Chrome browser from Chrome Web Store it shows the following error:

```
Could not install package:
'UTILITY_PROCESS_CRASHED_WHILE_TRYING_TO_INSTALL'. 
Could not install package because a utility process crashed. 
Try restarting Chrome and trying again.
```

I don't know what to do. And I can't find a proper solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is a bug in chrome, please downgrade your chrome browser or please wait for new version.

Answer (score 5):

This is [an unidentified bug in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=401655) that [made a lot of noise](http://linux.slashdot.org/story/15/03/08/1224210/google-chrome-requires-tsync-support-under-linux).

Since Chrome developers could not obtain feedback about this bug in time, they marked it as WontFix. **So simply waiting for a new version will most probably not help.**

> Closing for lack of actionable input on the bug.
>   If someone runs into this, please open a new bug!

You (yes, you, [007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4648369/007)!) can actually help everyone running into this bug. [Create an issue](https://crbug.com/new) at crbug.com, **mentioning the old issue #401655** and following the debug steps outlined in that issue report, esp. [this comment](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=401655#c87).

---

That said, the bug is correlated with the kernel version used. Ubuntu 12.10 is [no longer supported since 2014-05-16](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/05/01/ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal-reaches-end-of-life-on-may-16-2014/). **You probably should move to 14.04 LTS release where this bug is not present.**

But if you can't do that for whatever reason, and/or are willing to help Chrome development team, please investigate and make a bug report! And add a comment afterwards pointing to the bug you make.

---

> [Thank you for helping us help you help us all.](http://i1.theportalwiki.net/img/3/32/GLaDOS_10_part1_entry-3.wav)

-- GLaDOS, *Portal*

Comment: Well I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I have the exact same problem. Uninstall / reinstall chrome doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @jde While it does sound unlikely, a recent kernel change could make this happen.. If you can reliably reproduce it, please file a new bug on crbug.com and reference the issue #401655 in it.

Comment: You were right! My Ubuntu 14.04 was upgraded from 12.10 and I don't know wwhy but I got stuck with kernel 3.8. I upgraded to 3.13 and now everything works perfectly. 
Hope it helps future readers.

Answer (score 0):

version 46.0.2490.80

Fixed utility_process_crashed_while_trying_to_install issue as below:

1. modify the crx suffix to zip, e.g foo.crx->foo.zip
2. unzip the foo.zip to one folder, c:\chrome\foo
3. open chrome://extensions/
   enable Developer Mode
4. "load unzipped extensions" and open c:\chrome\foo
5. foo.crx loaded successfully.

As crx is zip file and only htm, json, js files included, it's chrome bug and 
hope this workaround will help you to avoid uninstall/install/upgrade pain :)